# c# printing - how do you define rectangles height when string size unknown

Tags: c#, printing

I have code that prints a till receipt which includes users string, the string is not fixed the user can type more or even less, thus i am not sure about the height, i have made a rectangle to print the users string and the height will be the amount of letters in the string, it works but when the string has more characters the receipt has a big white gap before it prints the string so basically not the right way.
this is the code that i have tried

```
graphics.DrawString("CONDITIONS OF SALE", bold2, Brushes.Black, 77, 70 + offX);//prints as stated

// after printing the string on top there is a big white space here. this is the issue.

SALE = dr2["PRINTMESSAGESALE"].ToString(); //gets string from database

var r = new Rectangle(2, 5 + offX, 275, SALE.Length); //rectangle that prints the string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C# Graphics.MeasureString method:

`public System.Drawing.SizeF MeasureString (string text, System.Drawing.Font font, int width);`

This will give you a SizeF instance declaring the width and height of a box containing the string, for a known constraining width.